# Can not access the relative path in javascript for Play framework 2.2.x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I am using echarts.js to render a fancy charts. But I render nothing on my view page. There is a callback function that need some params which is a specific relative path and I have to hardcoding it as following snippet of code:

```
require(
    [
        '/assets/javascripts/echarts/echarts',
        '/assets/javascripts/echarts/chart/bar',
        '/assets/javascripts/echarts/chart/line', 
        '/assets/javascripts/echarts/chart/pie' 
    ],
    DrawCharts
);
```

The worse is I found in echarts.js there are plenty of relative paths used in this echarts js framework. i.e.,

```
...
define("echarts/config", [], function() {
...

...
define("echarts/chart/island", ["require", "./base", "zrender/shape/Circle", "../config", "../util/ecData", "zrender/tool/util", "zrender/tool/event", "zrender/tool/color", "../util/accMath", "../chart"]
...
```

I sense it maybe the root cause of failing to render page and it is kind of silly and impossible if hardcoding these relative paths. So, is there any better solution?

Here is my js assets structure:
[image]